# Add to compare and wishlist not showing for custom module products

Tags: magento2

Why are the 'Add to compare' and 'Add to wishlist' option not coming for the products in frontend when i hover the mouse over the product.

Comment: please show your code to debug

Comment: Where are these controls(compare and wishlist) coming from? which code of my custom module to post... Cause i have not used in my code